# How to work with the cmp parameter in assembly x86

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm having problems in my cmp commands. No matter what result I may pass, the program ignores the cmp result and runs all parts of my code. Can anyone help me please?

```
     ;tipo de bandeira
    mov ah, 40h
    mov bx, 1
    mov cx, 24
    mov dx, bandeira
    int 21h

    ;linha
    mov ah, 40h
    mov bx, 1
    mov cx, 1
    mov dx, linha
    int 21h

    ;input e confirmação do tipo de bandeira
    mov ah, 3Fh
    mov bx, 00
    mov cx, 1
    mov dx, tipoBandeira
    int 21h

    ;clear feed
    mov ah, 3Fh
    mov bx, 00
    mov cx, 2
    mov dx, crlf
    int 21h

    cmp[tipoBandeira],01
    je T1
    cmp[tipoBandeira],02
    je T2


    T1:
    mov ah, 40h
    mov bx, 1
    mov cx, 08
    mov dx, quad
    int 21h

    T2:
    mov ah, 40h
    mov bx, 1
    mov cx, 11
    mov dx, rect
    int 21h
```

I'm pretty new to assembly, and I have a pretty lousy teacher that awnsers all our questions with "use google", ignoring that there are a lot of assembly types and that it really isn't a straight-forward language.

Comment: After the `je T2` if the condition is failed the code execution continues so that will run your `T1`. Also, after `T1` the code continues into `T2`. You should add some unconditional jump to avoid the fall-through. Draw a flowchart if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with

```
cmp [tipoBandeira],01
je T1
cmp [tipoBandeira],02
je T2

T1:
mov ah, 40h
mov bx, 1
mov cx, 08
mov dx, quad
int 21h

T2:
mov ah, 40h
mov bx, 1
mov cx, 11
mov dx, rect
int 21h
```

is the following:

- if [tipoBandeira] = 1, then execute T1, then T2
- if [tipoBandeira] = 2, then execute T2
- if [tipoBandeira] other, then execute T1, then execute T2

You're missing exits from compare and T1 blocks.
What you want is probably something like:

```
cmp [tipoBandeira],02  ;if tipoBandeira = 2
je T2                  ;  go to T2
cmp [tipoBandeira],01  ;else if tipoBandeira = 1
jne EXIT               ;  go to T1
                       ;else go to EXIT
T1:
mov ah, 40h
mov bx, 1
mov cx, 08
mov dx, quad
int 21h
jmp EXIT                ;end if

T2:
mov ah, 40h
mov bx, 1
mov cx, 11
mov dx, rect
int 21h

EXIT:                   ;end if
...
```

Comment: i usually work in c so this language is a bit confusing for me. i originally wanted some sort of if-statement so that, if tipoBandeira is equal to 1 it would run T1 but not T2. also what does EXIT: do? i would need to run a separate code if any of the conditions were true, would that code be in exit?

Comment: `separate code if any of the conditions were true` yes, unless by "any condition" you mean really any, but not only `if (var == 1 || var == 2)`. jumps are simple - if you need to skip some part - jump over it

Comment: ok, so i altered the code to:
        cmp [tipoBandeira],01
        je T1
       cmp [tipoBandeira],02
        jmp T2

       T1:
       mov ah, 40h
       mov bx, 1
       mov cx, 08
       mov dx, quad
       int 21h
       jmp s1

       T2:
       mov ah, 40h
       mov bx, 1
       mov cx, 11
       mov dx, rect
       int 21h

       s1:

thing is, i would then have to ask and compare another value and, by using both values, draw either a x-color square or rectangle. Would i have to then use 2 cmp´s or just jump from part to part?

Comment: `cmp [tipoBandeira],02 / jmp T2` this one will be taken always. should be `je T2 / jmp <code_which_will_run_if_neither_1_nor_2>`